# Streaming from PC to media player

Tags: streaming

My biggest concern is that I have Philips media player HMP5000 and I don't know if I'll be able to stream movies from my pc with Linux Ubuntu? I want to have only one OS on pc..

Comment: Does is have "stream over network" feature? You forgot to mention that. :~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it supports DLNA. To share your videos, you have to set up a DLNA server on your Ubuntu PC, f.e. ReadyMedia, formerly`minidlna`.

### **SETUP GUIDE MINIDLNA**

1. Open a Terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) on your Ubuntu machine.
2. Install the DLNA server using `sudo apt-get install minidlna`
3. Edit the config file of minidlna `sudo nano /etc/minidlna.conf` and change the following lines:

   ```
   media_dir=/path/to/your/videos
   friendly_name=My supercool DLNA Server
   inotify=yes
   ```

   Don't forget to change the path to your videos ;)
4. Restart minidlna daemon. `sudo service minidlna restart`
5. Done! You can now check the status of minidlna by accessing `localhost:8200` from your Ubuntu machine's web browser.

---

If you connect your media player to your network, you should be able to see a DLNA Server called "My supercool DLNA Server", or whatever you specified in `friendly_name`. You can access it and all video files should be available there. If you select one, it should start playing it.